# Slider feature seems to break my html/CSS on my webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been having some issues with a page on my website. Up until this morning everything was working quite nicely until i got to this page and i cannot figure it out.

[The page in question](http://wpdev.quadris.co.uk/on-premise)

I've removed the CSS from the page that i think is causing the problem but il add it here in case anyone wants to check it out.

It would seem that everything works until i add the styles for the content boxes, then its like there is a margin or some positioning taking over and moving the slider in the header down the page, behind the content boxes.

[Where it should be](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnfnv1wqs2ntm5s/where-it-should-be.png?dl=0)
[Where it actually is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o36j4wf6pdtb78h/where-it-is-after-css.png?dl=0)

As you can see in the screenshots the content box sits over the top of the slider/header when it should not. it only does this once i add the CSS to position and format the content boxes. the CSS below

```css
.box img {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
}

.box .qfont{
      position: absolute;
top: 25%;    left: 45%;
    font-size: 82px;
    color: #424545;
    opacity: 0.9;

}
/*Initial settings for the box container*/

.fl-module-content {
    margin: 1%;
}
.box {
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 340px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 99%;
}
/*Position icons towards the center and bottom of the box, done this way otherwise the buttons appear uneven*/
.box .fa {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 48px;
}
/*.box .dashicons, .box .dashicons-before:before  {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 40%;
    font-size: 48px;
}*/
.box i[class^="quad"] {
      position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 52px;

}
.box .fa {
    color: #009933;
     position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 40%;
    font-size: 52px;

}
/*SPosition the header*/
.box h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 38px;
  width: 99%;
  top: 1%;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  text-align: center;
  
}
/*Position the Paragraph*/
.box p{
      text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    padding: 3%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*apply styles and centre the text of the hidden content*/
.box .overbox p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #424545;
    font-size: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;

}
/*styles for the hidden content container and hides the content*/
.box .overbox {
    border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #424545;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
    padding: 30px 20px;


    
}

/*restores opacity on mouse over, displaying the main container for the hidden content*/
.box:hover .overbox { opacity: 1; }

.box .overtext {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  height: 90%;
}
/*hides the remaining content until roll over*/
.box .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  height: 90%;
}
/*Restore hidden content on mouse over*/
.box:hover .title,
.box:focus .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}
/*hides the button*/
.overbox .tagline {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color:#fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
/*restore the button*/
.box:hover .tagline,
.box:focus .tagline {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-primary {
    border-style: none;
}
.box a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*button is built on bootstrap CSS, most of the styles for dimensions and responsiveness are in bootstrap file. 
We just change the colour and position it to the bottom of its container*/
.box .overbox .btn-primary {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #9e3039;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: none;
    left: 80%;

} 
/*Change the link hover effect so the text is white.*/
.box .overbox .btn-primary a, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.box .overbox p {
          text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    padding: 3%;
    padding-top: 0;
    
}

.box .overbox ul, li {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1%;
    
}
```

FYI, it is a WordPress website and I'm using Beaver Builder to make the pages, i would be inclined to think it is a theme issue but i have a similar set up on some other pages that work

[Home page with similar setup](http://wpdev.quadris.co.uk/home-3)

I accept the layout is slightly different, but the CSS is pretty much the same, just some different dimensions and slight element positioning to take up more of the screen real estate.

Has anybody got an ideas? I've read through the code numerous times it all looks the same now, so if someone could point me in the right direction, or offer some advice it would be much appreciated. Il move onto a different page for now so as to not effect it if anyone is looking at it.

Any more info just ask and i'll provide.

Many thanks,

PhilB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below style in your code.

```
.soliloquy-item{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Legend!

the soliloquy should have been aligned to 0 0 in the slider settings so i dont know what happened, but i never even looked in there.

Comment: Sorry, pressed return to go down a  line and it didnt work. Thank you @Sasikumar

Comment: No, thank you. I would have spent the rest of the day trying to figure it out. 

PhilB